# Is there a way to tell C compiler to inline a variable?

Tags: c, compilation, compiler-optimization, chess

I am a relatively new C programmer and I am writing a chess program that I want to make sure it runs as fast as possible. Here is a snippet of code from my program inside a loop in which I am encoding moves into a 16-bit variable. Each square takes up 6 bits.

```
Square targetSquare = GET_LS1B(leftPawnAttacks);
moveList[i] = (targetSquare << 4) | ((targetSquare - 7) << 10);
```

What I want to do, to improve readability, is define a new variable called `originSquare` like so

```
Square targetSquare = GET_LS1B(leftPawnAttacks);
Square originSquare = targetSquare - 7;
moveList[i] = (targetSquare << 4) | (originSquare << 10);
```

So the first 6 bits represent the origin square of the move and the next 6 represent the target square. In this particular loop, all the moves will be of the same type: the origin square will always be -7 from the target.

I don't want to waste instructions declaring `Square originSquare` and then looking up its value 1 line later, since this section of a loop is running thousands of times per second.

**My question is: is there a way to tell the C compiler or preprocessor to just shove `targetSquare - 7` where it sees `originSquare` within the scope of this loop, i.e. inline the variable, or will it do this already?**

My best guess is that if I declare the variable const the compiler will likely do this on its own, but I'd like to be sure and learn more about C and compilation.

Comment: `-O3` is usually enough

Comment: Sounds like `#define originSquare  (targetSquare - 7)` . But this is exactly what will "waste" the instructions. In your approach the calculation will only happen once, in the macro approach it will happen each iteration (well, it won't in fact as any sane compiler will optimize it, but it would *look* like it is happening every iteration).

Comment: @EugeneSh. Right, but I have other loops through different types of moves where the originSquare = targetSquare - 9, or some other value that needs to be calculated. Also in each iteration of the loop, the targetValue is different so it has to be calculated each iteration.

Comment: The second snippet is good enough, there is no "waste of instructions"

Comment: If the `Square` type is primitive, you can declare `register Square originSquare = targetSquare - 7;`. This is deprecated in c++ (but not in c) for good reason: It's pointless for optimizing compilers, because they optimize better than you can.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: `-Ofast` tries even harder than `-O3`, see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html

Comment: @EOF `register` keyword is ignored by the modern compilers

Comment: @csowerby moder opimizing compilers will get rid of this variable for you. Simple focus on your algorithm and foreger about micro optimizations.

Comment: @pmg Yeah, but "_Disregard strict standards compliance_" and I doubt `-ffast-math` or `-fallow-store-data-races` makes any difference here.

Comment: If you want to micro optimize, you need to learn how to read assembly. Then you can request the assembly from the compiler using the `-S` option (gcc or clang). Or you can view the assembly in the debugger. Looking at the assembly allows you to experiment, and see what the compiler does with your code. Of course you need to enable optimizations (`-O3`).

Comment: `targetSquare` is apparently less than 64, in which case `(targetSquare << 4) | ((targetSquare - 7) << 10)` equals `targetSquare * 1040 - 7168`. So, for speed, just write that (with comments clearly documenting the intended effect). For readability, write it as a macro or an inline function (and check the generated assembly). A multiplication and a subtraction is fast in many common modern processors, so you will not beat that. (If you are writing for some low-end processor, there might be more to consider.)

Comment: @csowerby In old days when processors were simple and compilers did what they were told, the definitive-ish answer was the `register` keyword. Even back then, the compiler was allowed to ignore the `register` keyword because it's easy for a programmer to declare more register variables than there are registers. Nowadays, compilers are inclined to completely ignore the `register` keyword, and all you can do is hope the optimizer gets it right.

Comment: obligatory comment to say that premature optimisation is the root of all evil... Honestly, focus on getting everything working as expected, then focus on getting it to work as fast as possible (or as fast as you need/want). Compilers optimise a lot already. Macros would be an option, but really, if this one variable is impacting performance, you're in a really good place already

Comment: The more effort you put into micro-optimising, the less you can focus on the efficiency of the algorithms used. And when you tune the algorithm, the effort spent micro-optimising was wasted.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem: That is a tired aphorism with little basis in practice. So-called premature optimization may displace novice programmers’ attention from other issues but has little effect otherwise—there is nothing wrong with making a small piece of code go faster while other issues remain, except for the fact that insufficient attention is given to those other issues. To the contrary, for an experienced programmer, keeping optimization in mind during design and other early phases is beneficial and helps avoid requiring work to redo things later.

Comment: Thanks everybody for your help, I've decided to not care about this issue and trust in -O3, but I learned a lot!

Comment: @EricPostpischil I agree with you said (hence I started out by saying my comment was _"the obligatory comment to say..."_). The OP clearly stated that he was new to C programming, so like you said: that places him in the category of people that may get side tracked. Even when I write go, I tend to stop & think about how much memory I'll be allocating, and how often. That's fine, but this level of detail for someone who said that they're relatively new to C might just be a case where the tired old aphorism is applicable